# Maven property plugin and overriding existing properties

Tags: maven

Could you please clarify, if I have next pom structure:

```
   ...
   <properties>
      <prop1>value</prop1>
   </properties>
   ...
   <plugin>
   ... here I read properties using properties-maven-plugin ...
   </plugin>
```

Is it possible to somehow specify, that properties from the property file should override properties which set in `<properties>` block?

For example, if property file contains property with name 'prop1' - then override existing property `<prop1>`.

Comment: By which goal do you read the properties?

Comment: @khmarbaise I use 'read-project-properties' for that